# Why does this method call on a null object run without a NullPointerException?

Tags: java

What is the reason for the output? I know it prints `Hello World` but don’t know why as it should give `NullPointerException`.

```
public class Null
{
    public static void greet()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ((Null)null).greet();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `greet()`is a static method. So

```
((Null)null).greet();
```

is equivalent to,

```
Null.greet()
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `greet` is a static method, a class instance is not needed (and not used...) to invoke it.

The `((Null)null)` expression doesn't dereference `null`, it simply serves as a type definition used to access the static method.

Answer (score 3):

When we attempt to use an object reference that has a null value, `NullPointerException` is thrown. So, in your example you may think that how `greet()` method is successfully called from a null object.

But, look at the method signature carefully, it has a `static` modifier in front of it. If you call a static method on an object with a null reference, you won’t get an exception and the code will run without any exception. That is because static methods are the class methods not the instance method.

So when you compile your code, `((Null)null).greet()` is simply converted to `Null.greet()`.

For simplicity, consider the code below:

```
Null obj1 = null;
Null obj2 = new Null();
obj1.greet();
obj2.greet();
```

As `greet()` is a static method here, during that method call compiler will simply ignore if there is anything inside the object created from it or not. It will be just compiled as `Null.greet()` for both `obj1` and `obj2`.

However, try to remove the `static` modifier from the method. You will find that `NullPointerException` you were expecting.

Answer (score 3):

This is valid behaviour since :

```
((Null)null).greet();
```

will be like calling a static method `greet` on `Null` class.

It is even shown as correct behaviour in example [`15.11.1-2. Receiver Variable Is Irrelevant For static Field Access`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1) of JLS :

> The following program demonstrates that a null reference may be used to access a class (static) variable without causing an exception:

```
class Test3 {
    static String mountain = "Chocorua";
    static Test3 favorite(){
        System.out.print("Mount ");
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(favorite().mountain);
    }
}
```

And the explanation on what is happening, why it compiles and prints `Mount Chocorua` :

> Even though the result of `favorite()` is `null`, a `NullPointerException` is not thrown. That "Mount " is printed demonstrates that the Primary expression is indeed fully evaluated at run time, despite the fact that only its type, not its value, is used to determine which field to access (because the field `mountain` is static).

So in your case that is only type of expression `((Null)null)` - that is evaluated to `Null` - that is used to determine which method to call ( there is a static method `greet` in `Null` class so it is not a problem).